# Wireguard + Split Tunnel + Two Peers -- Handshake failure with second peer because of private key

Tags: vpn, wireguard

I've setup **two wireguard peer servers** and can connect sucessfully to each one independetly.

But when I try to connect to two peers at same time and split tunnels, **It does fails to hand shake with second server**.
I think thats because two peers private keys are different, and In multi peer client I can only enter one server's private key.

I don't know how can these two peers work together with one private key?

**My main goal is to setup two peer servers and split tunnel for specific range ip.**

Here I've pasted two servers and peers config and also multi peer client. Would appreciate any help.

```
Server 1:
[Interface] 
Address = 10.7.0.1/24 
PrivateKey = EKSCFdQiAgXsL4Wm40z63fdXL7q4PCgyB4XhNqkq+1A= 
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = G5ZurqtqfiMCgkImUfA+R17r3IaYhAh/jWZpNtB/4iI=
PresharedKey = mekE11iavS70vbJ/mLunFxRDEzYwXuGX2wdCZw8FFyc=
AllowedIPs = 10.7.0.2/32
```

```
Server 2:
[Interface]
Address = 10.7.0.1/24
PrivateKey = +IapZjrB8UfiTdsJNUWIFntK00z2v6MTpeYqHVMMTmI=
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = l7YElLKnNWLUmohKpR+rQDORLmXm5geAivz9AzbbvkE=
PresharedKey = J+kdful8xJW1uMdVGfrDM+D2v/dyl/Y8SYp+0/rS/mM=
AllowedIPs = 10.7.0.2/32
```

- Note that I've tried and managed to get same range ip (10.7.0.2) on both servers. don't know is it necessary or causing problem or not.

```
Peer 1 config:
[Interface] 
Address = 10.7.0.2/24 
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 
PrivateKey = WMrHIjr71kv7Cl3zw9mx72d8uCTmLJPDk6K0j7FWjmg=

[Peer]
PublicKey = gu78igdrkMzlowf8988zYt58ciI0DTmz4QMzZ1QgfCs=
PresharedKey = mekE11iavS70vbJ/mLunFxRDEzYwXuGX2wdCZw8FFyc=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = SERVER_A:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

```
Peer 2 config:
[Interface]
Address = 10.7.0.2/24
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
PrivateKey = yNGP/MbTAjyADyTLuv19PwL5rCj6Q8j/hJGVz+Cafko=

[Peer]
PublicKey = HdYcIUebtkxiXWwcvaef8Z+/wrEqV7ArzL4Jbknus3A=
PresharedKey = J+kdful8xJW1uMdVGfrDM+D2v/dyl/Y8SYp+0/rS/mM=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = SERVER_2:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

**And finally, the multi peer config i'm trying to use but fail:
Client config:**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.7.0.2/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
PrivateKey = yNGP/MbTAjyADyTLuv19PwL5rCj6Q8j/hJGVz+Cafko=

[Peer]
PublicKey = HdYcIUebtkxiXWwcvaef8Z+/wrEqV7ArzL4Jbknus3A=
PresharedKey = J+kdful8xJW1uMdVGfrDM+D2v/dyl/Y8SYp+0/rS/mM=
AllowedIPs = 8.0.0.0/8
Endpoint = SERVER_2:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

[Peer]
PublicKey = gu78igdrkMzlowf8988zYt58ciI0DTmz4QMzZ1QgfCs=
PresharedKey = mekE11iavS70vbJ/mLunFxRDEzYwXuGX2wdCZw8FFyc=
AllowedIPs = 45.0.0.0/8
Endpoint = SERVER_A:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Wireguard logs from second server which fails to handshake as private key issue:

kernel: [70290.070053] wireguard: wg0: Invalid handshake initiation from MY_IP:64230

kernel: [70295.369403] wireguard: wg0: Invalid handshake initiation from MY_IP:64230

kernel: [70300.569581] wireguard: wg0: Invalid handshake initiation from MY_IP:64230

**Can anybody help me how can I achieve split tunnel using two peers and fixing this private key issue? Thanks.**

Comment: Why is your client using the same private key as one of its peers?

Comment: @user1686 I thought I might use first peer's Interface as base and then append second peer to it. Am I did it wrong? If so, which private key should I put in the client? Thanks.

Comment: @user1686 Also please note those configs that have same private keys are both client configs and not server. I just tried to merge both peer clients so I reach the goal of multi peer splitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to wireguard's IRC channel #wireguard members, finally the problem has been solved.

To fix it, the public key in two server's [Peer] must be same.

In my example, I had to put "l7YElLKnNWLUmohKpR+rQDORLmXm5geAivz9AzbbvkE=" in server 1 [Peer] PublicKey field.

This fixed the problem.